# how to call optiontree taxonomy select

Tags: wordpress

I ask for help to solve my problem, I use the option-tree framework for displaying custom posts from specific categories, I have this code:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $category_product1 = ot_get_option( 'homepage-slider-cat1' );
    $args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'numberposts'    => 18,
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'category' => $category_product1,
       'include_children' => true
    );
?>
```

with this post code specific category does not appear.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Tax_query` as a query parameter? This way you can query on `taxonomies`.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'people',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'bob',
    ),
),
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters